# How can I return an array of urls as links in html using google apps scripts

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet containing a list of urls in a single column.  I would like to publish a web app that adds a specified number of urls to an array and then  return that array as html.
I have searched and tried dozens of ways to do it but the best I can do is return it as comma separated text using ContentService.createTextOutput.  Any attempts at using html service fail, at best returning undefined.
Below is the code I am currently using.  It works just as I want, up until returning the results.  My coding knowledge is very limited and kind of all over the place including python, php, and javascript/google scripts.  Any help in guiding me to a working solution would be so appreciated.

```
function doGet() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bRo9zY_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-j_n10D9r-M");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1);
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();  
var row = cell.getRow();
var col = cell.getColumn();
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
var data = range.getValue();  
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var arr = [];
var qnty = 5

for (var i = 0; i < qnty; i++) {

  arr.push(data); 
  range.clear();
  try {
     sheet.getRange(row + numRows, col, lastRow - row - numRows + 1,                                        numCols).moveTo(sheet.getRange(row, col, lastRow - row - numRows + 1, numCols));
     sheet.getRange(lastRow - numRows + 1, col, numRows, numCols).clearContent();

    var data = range.getValue();
 }
  catch(err) {
    if (row + numRows > lastRow) {
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Select a different range: Cannot shift up           from the last populated row of a sheet.');
} else {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Could not move data: Please make sure nobody         else is editing the column(s) and try again.');
}  
  Logger.log( arr.length); 

}
}

 return ContentService.createTextOutput([arr]);
}
```

Comment: have you tried on the last line passing JSON.stringify(arr) instead of [arr]

Answer (score 0):

after the first for loop try this

```
for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    arr[x] = "<a href=\"" + arr[x] + "\">" + arr[x] + "</a>";
}
return ContentService.createTextOutput(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Your solution does return the correct format for a link but the output is still text.  Is there a way I could retrieve that data to the server and then linkify using json2html?